# find and replace in multiple files on command line

Tags: unix, command-line, command-line-arguments

How do i find and replace a string on command line in multiple files on unix?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find and replace a particular term in multiple files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263925/find-and-replace-a-particular-term-in-multiple-files)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

there are many ways .But one of the answers would be:

```
find . -name '*.html' |xargs perl -pi -e 's/find/replace/g'
```

Answer (score 37):

Like the Zombie solution (and faster I assume) but with **sed** (standard on many distros and OSX) instead of Perl :

```
find . -name '*.py' | xargs sed -i .bak 's/foo/bar/g'
```

This will replace all *foo* occurences in your Python files below the current directory with *bar* and create a backup for each file with the *.py.bak* extension.

And to remove de .bak files:

```
find . -name "*.bak" -delete
```

Comment: This affects whitespace outside of the search. It seemed to add new lines to the end of each of my files.

Comment: AFAIK in-place editing is not supported in every version of sed; I think it's a GNU extension.

Comment: it's a gnu extension and at least in my version it has to be
`sed -i.bak`
(no space)

Comment: my version works with -i without needing to specify .bak extension

Comment: This fails if you have a folder named ".py"

Comment: This will only touch files and won't generate .bak files: `find . -type f -name '*.py' | xargs sed -i"" 's/foo/bar/g'`

Answer (score 7):

I always did that with ***ed scripts*** or ***ex scripts***.

```
for i in "$@"; do ex - "$i" << 'eof'; done
%s/old/new/
x
eof
```

The ***ex*** command is just the : line mode from vi.

Comment: This has the distinct advantage that you can perform more sophisticated edits.

Answer (score 7):

Using find and sed with name or directories with space use this:

```
find . -name '*.py' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/foo/bar/g'
```

Answer (score 2):

with recent bash shell, and assuming you do not need to traverse directories

```
for file in *.txt
do
while read -r line
do
    echo ${line//find/replace} > temp        
done <"file"
mv temp "$file"
done
```