# Find and replace a particular term in multiple files

Tags: linux, search, ubuntu, replace

How can I replace a particular term in multiple files in Linux?

For instance, I have a number of files in my directory:

file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt

And I need to find a word "searchword" and replace it with "replaceword".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
sed -i.bak 's/searchword/replaceword/g' file*.txt
# Or sed -i.bak '/searchword/s/searchword/replaceword/g' file*.txt
```

With bash 4.0, you can do recursive search for files

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/file*.txt
do 
  sed -i.bak 's/searchword/replaceword/g' $file
  # or sed -i.bak '/searchword/s/searchword/replaceword/g' $file
done
```

Or with GNU find

```
find /path -type f -iname "file*.txt" -exec sed -i.bak 's/searchword/replace/g' "{}" +;
```

Comment: The second option can be shortened to sed -i.bak '/searchword/s//replaceword/g'

Comment: the second option traverse subdirectories.

Comment: @ghostdog: You miss the point of my comment.  With sed, you do not need to specify the searchword twice.

Answer (score 12):

Nothing spectacular but thought this might be of help to others. Though you can write a shell script to do this easily, this one-liner is perhaps easier:

```
grep -lr -e '<searchthis>' * | xargs sed -i 's/<searchthis>/<replacewith>/g'
```

Comment: You can also just do `sed 's<searchthis>/<replacewith>/g' -i *`

Comment: Ah... even simpler.. :) Thanks!

Comment: @Code Duck - this will avoid invoking `sed` where there is no search term present. More efficient - I guess - when the files are large.

Comment: @ Tom Duckering : I thought of that too, but then realized the first example is greping through each file in the directory to find the term, too. Sed may or may not be as efficient as grep at doing that, but anyhow it seems simpler to just use one command.

Comment: @Code Duck - yeah - the usual trade one makes in adding complexity to make something more efficient. :)

Comment: It's unclear whether searching through the files with grep is more efficient than searching through the files with sed.  Either way, every line of each file is being sifted through.

Comment: @ Tom Duckering: Actually, the grep/xargs/sed one is less efficient: you are opening every file, searching it, then reopening matching files with sed. With the sed only style, you are simply opening every file. So, it's like O(n+x) vs. O(n).

Answer (score 2):

#### Use an ed script

Although sed now has an in-place edit option, you can also use the ed or ex program for this purpose...

```
for i in "$@"; do ed "$i" << \eof; done
1,$s/searchword/replaceword/g
w
q
eof
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://gist.github.com/dvdsgl/4600317) ruby script worked for me, also renames the files/folders with that typo in too.

Answer (score 0):

Try [mffr](http://github.com/cybertk/mffr) if you are in a git repo

```
pip install mffr
mffr searchword replaceword
```