# Find and replace punctuation character in first column for multiple text files

Tags: perl, replace, punctuation

Need a solution similar to this post ([Find and replace a particular term in multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263925/find-and-replace-a-particular-term-in-multiple-files)) but for a punctuation character replacement in the first column of each delimited tab text file.

Example:

```
file1.txt
afile2.txt
3file.txt
...
```

all other file names end with .txt

Format of txt files has a "tab" in between column and look like:

```
aaaa:bbb    second_column    third_column
w:xyz    another_second_column    another_third_column
```

I need to replace the `:` in the first column to another character such as `##`.

Please help.

Does perl treat the `:` character as a column cutter?

Comment: Based on your comments, I get the feeling that you are asking [The Wrong Question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/45154/13917). Why do you want to remove the colon? It is not a meta character in perl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace inplace the first colon in the first tab-delimited column in a line by `##`:

```
perl -i.bak -pe's/^([^\t:]*):/$1##/' *.txt
```

It processes all .txt-files in the current directory saving backup versions to .bak-files.

Here's a variant that doesn't require the capture (suggested by @Brad Gilbert in the comments):

```
perl -i.bak -pe's/^[^\t:]*\K:/##/' *.txt
```

Both scripts produce the same result.

Comment: `s/:/##/` would be enough. However +1.

Comment: I get the first column chopped off whenever there is a ":" character. That's why I need the replacement. What does ":" do in perl?  Yes, the ^\t will leave the 2nd and 3rd column untouched.

Comment: @M42: It the first column doesn't have `:` then `s/:/##/` is wrong.

Comment: @horkust: Construct a minimal example that demonstrates your problem (with the smallest input, your code that processes it, expected output, and what you get instead) and [post it as a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: `perl -i.bak -pe's/^[^\t:]*\K:/##/' *.txt` works on newer versions of Perl