# find and replace strings in files in a particular directory

Tags: regex, sed, find, pattern-matching

I have a pattern that I need to replace in my `.hpp`, `.h`, `.cpp` files in multiple directories.

I have read [Find and replace a particular term in multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263925/find-and-replace-a-particular-term-in-multiple-files) question for guidance. I am also using [this](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-7) tutorial but I am not able achieve what I intend to do. So here is my pattern.

```
throw some::lengthy::exception();
```

I want to replace it with this

```
throw CreateException(some::lengthy::exception());
```

How can I achieve this?

UPDATE:

Moreover, what if the `some::lengthy::exception()` part is variant such that it changes for every search result ? 
Something like

`throw some::changing::text::exception();`

will be converted to

`throw CreateException(some::changing::text::exception());`

Comment: My bad. Yes, it does not contain `[` or `]` characters.

Comment: But how would you define the `throw` sentence? Just a line starting with `throw` and ending with `();`?

Comment: @fedorqui..I have updated the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `sed` expression:

```
sed 's/throw some::lengthy::exception();/throw CreateException(some::lengthy::exception());/g'
```

And add it into a `find` command to check `.h`, `.cpp` and `.hpp` files (idea coming from [List files with certain extensions with ls and grep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1448069/1983854)):

```
find . -iregex '.*\.\(h\|cpp\|hpp\)'
```

All together:

```
find . -iregex '.*\.\(h\|cpp\|hpp\)' -exec sed -i.bak 's/throw some::lengthy::exception();/throw CreateException(some::lengthy::exception());/g' {} \;
```

Note the usage of `sed -i.bak` in order to to edits in place but create a `file.bak` backup file.

### Variable pattern

If your pattern varies, you can use:

```
sed -r '/^throw/s/throw (.*);$/throw CreateException(\1);/' file
```

This does the replacement in the lines starting with `throw`. It catches everything after `throw` up to `;` and prints it back surrounded by CreateException();`.

#### Test

```
$ cat a.hpp 
throw some::lengthy::exception();
throw you();
asdfasdf throw you();
$ sed -r '/^throw/s/throw (.*);$/throw CreateException(\1);/' a.hpp 
throw CreateException(some::lengthy::exception());
throw CreateException(you());
asdfasdf throw you();
```

Comment: Ok.Thanks for this. But what if the `some::lengthy::exception()` part is variant? And changes for every search result ?  Something like `throw [I change everytime]` will be converted to `throw CreateException([I change everytime]);`

Comment: @Recker for this I need you to update your question with a better set of sample input and desired output : )

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below sed command.

```
sed 's/\bthrow some::lengthy::exception();/throw CreateException(some::lengthy::exception());/g' *.cpp
```

Add inline-edit `-i` param to save the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
sed 's/\b(throw some::lengthy::exception());/throw CreateException(\1);/g'
```

Comment: Except this won't work, since `sed(1)` needs BRE syntax while your answer uses Perl regexps.

Comment: Nope.  Grouping `(...)` should be `\(...\)`, and `\b` doesn't exist in `sed(1)`.  But `\1` is fine.

Comment: @lcd047 .. http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_tool_guides/the_sed_faq/sedfaq6_009.html says `\b` can be used as word boundaries in sed.. no?

Comment: Then they are wrong.  `\b` has never been a word delimiter in `sed(1)`.  It stands for the backspace character in BSD `sed(1)`, and it's undefined for most versions of GNU `sed(1)`. _shrug_

Comment: Sorry, actually `\b` seems to work in recent versions of GNU `sed(1)`.  It's probably still not a good idea to use it though.

Comment: @lcd047 .. well.. i dont use sed much.. but i saw answers (accepted) with `\b` as word boundary.. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032023/sed-whole-word-search-and-replace