# Complex Find and Replace in unix command line

Tags: regex, perl, unix, command-line, command

I'm trying to do a complex find and replace in all files through unix command line using the answer provided in [find and replace in multiple files on command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895819/find-and-replace-in-multiple-files-on-command-line) but I can't seem to get my find and replace strings escaped properly.

I need to find all lines that contain:

```
if ($session['test']>0){
```

and replace it with

```
if ($session['test']>1){
```

The command I'm trying is:

```
find . -name '*.php' |xargs perl -pi -e 's/if\(\$session\[\'test\'\]\>0\){/if\(\$session\[\'test\'\]\>1\){/g'
```

But that gives me another prompt which requires me to enter an additional `'` character because the command tells me there's a string that's missing termination.  If I put it in extra `'` at the end, I get:

```
Unmatched ) in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/if\(\$session\[\test']>0) <-- HERE {/ at -e line 1.
```

How do I get this replacement to work?

Comment: Commands don't "think". They *know*.

Comment: When shell interpolation is an issue, just use a file to hold your regex and run `xargs perl -pi file.pl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use double quotes:

```
perl -pi -e "s/if\(\$session\[\'test\'\]\>0\){/if\(\$session\[\'test\'\]\>1\){/g"
```

Moreover, you are missing a space after `if` and the dollar sign needs to be escaped with three backslashes:

```
perl -pi -e "s/if \(\\\$session\[\'test\'\]\>0\){/if \(\\\$session\[\'test\'\]\>1\){/g"
                 ^  ^^^                                ^^^
```

Comment: Using double quotes results in a successful run of the command but doesn't achieve the replacement I intended.

Answer (score 2):

Using double quotes and double escaping the `$` works:

```
perl -pi -e "s/if \(\\\$session\['text'\]>0\){/if (\\\$session['text']>1){/"
```

A shorter but dirtier solution with a look-behind and look-ahead assertions:

```
perl -pi -e 's/(?<=if \(\$session\[.text.\]>)0(?=\){)/1/'
```