# how to move a apache localhost website to internet (i.e remote server)

Tags: php, apache, web-config, localhost, remote-server

i have few conceptual queries about moving a locahost site to server for making it available on internet.....**what are the steps**...how server will recognize the changes in my apache and php config files..i have built a website in php and mysql on apache 2.2

**NOTES:**

- i have made some changes in my apache config files.one of them is i
  have included a fillename ***"index.php"*** in
  ***"DirectoryIndex"***...so now my DirectoryIndex looks like:

  ```
  <IfModule dir_module>
      DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  </IfModule>
  ```
- so now automatically my apache tells the browser to search for a index.php file whenever **header('LOCATION:') or refresh** is called.and it's obvious that my index.php files holdas the html and and other php codes which will be shown or displayed
- third and most importantly...**i have used header function in many cases while building the website..my header functions are like `header('Location: http://localhost/home/');`**

so repeating the question again

- should i change all the header functions while uploading acording to my website name
  i.e

  `header('Location: http://www.my_site_name.com/home/');` in place of

  `header('Location: http://localhost/home/');`
- and who will my remote server will recognize the changes i have made in my config file and will work according to the changes
- and what are the steps to upload a website to internet

Comment: use a constant to store `http://localhost/` and for  [replacing strings in multiple files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895819/find-and-replace-in-multiple-files-on-command-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and who will my remote server will recognize the changes i have made
>   in my config file and will work according to the changes

Normally hosting servers are configured to allow the use of .htaccess files to override apache configuration

you may create a **.htaccess** file in your root directory and place there your DirectoryIndex settings

Comment: am sorry..am have very few knowledge about that....what is .htaccess file ..what i should write into that...and root directory of what????

Comment: does this file will help my remote server to acknowledgfe the changes in my con fig files of php and apache

Comment: You cannot access directly the apache configuration of a webhosting. If you want to replicate your "<IfModule dir_module>  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php <IfModule>" rule on your webhosting you have to create a textfile named **.htaccesss** in your site root directory (where you have your base index.html file). In this file simply copy **DirectoryIndex index.html index.php**.

Comment: Again, you cannot access directly php.ini files so, if you need particular settings you have to use the php **ini_set** function. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php. Not all possible php.ini settings are supported via ini_set though.

Comment: **.htaccess** file and **ini_set** function are the only way to interfere with apache and php configuration on a server where you don't have administration access (where you cannot edit php.ini and httpd.conf)

Comment: unable to upvote..don't have that much reputation...so i just need to add that `.htaccess` file right???..nothing else right??

Comment: one last question please..where should i use this ini_set function..in every code????..or in `.htaccess`?????..

Comment: right, nothing else. If you don't notice any changes try using another browser or clear you cache. Note that not all the server supports .htaccess overriding but the majority does

Comment: one last question please..where should i use this ini_set function..in every code????..or in .htaccess?????..

Comment: Normally web applications have one php config file (config.php or something like that) included in every file (require_once). This is the right place to put settings needed for the whole project such as constants (database connection vars), paths (as said by @Shikiryu you should prefer relative paths when applicable), etc .. and your ini_set calls.

Answer (score 0):

> should i change all the header functions while uploading acording to
>   my website name i.e `header('Location: http://www.my_site_name.com/home/');`
>   in place of `header('Location: http://localhost/home/')`;

Why not using relative paths or simply:

```
header('Location: /home/');
```

> and who will my remote server will recognize the changes i have made
>   in my config file and will work according to the changes

That way, it'll work on both servers.

> and what are the steps to upload a website to internet

You should use a FTP client to upload your website to your webhost.

Comment: `That way, it'll work on both servers.`..

how remote server will undesrstand my "DirectoryIndex" change

Comment: so i need not to write something like `header('Location: http://www.my_site_name.com/home/');`..right????

Comment: Your `DirectoryIndex` is the same on both server right? Do you know what's its use? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

Comment: @SarthokBhattacharya why don't you try for yourself? :)

Comment: DirectoryIndex tells Apache which filenames to use when it looks for the default page for a given directory.i know it..my question was by default there was not index.php..i have added it...so how remote server will understand that i have added index.php in DirectoryIndex

Comment: @SarthokBhattacharya Modify your `DirectoryIndex` so as it will be the same on both server (as I told you 20mins ago). I guess it's in a .htaccess file. If it's the case, upload your local one to your server and it's done.

Comment: @SarthokBhattacharya `DirectoryIndex` is not about PHP but APACHE. You can change it in httpd.conf if you want. (or still .htaccess)